# Minimal user profile to backup?

Tags: google-chrome

From the default Google Chrome 67 user profile on Windows 10

```
C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

What are the MINIMAL files/folders to backup to get back ONLY:

```
Chrome settings
User Bookmarks
User Cookies
User Extensions and their settings
```

after copying those files/folders in an empty folder (same or other PC):

```
C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\User2
```

and starting

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --Profile-DiRECTORY="User2"
```

This list works fine sometime but sometime not (folder name ending by backslash):

```
data_reduction_proxy_leveldb\
databases\
Extension Rules\
Extension State\
Extensions\
IndexedDB\
Local Extension Settings\
Local Storage\
Managed Extension Settings\
Service Worker\
Session Storage\
Sync Extension Settings\
Web Applications\

Bookmarks
Cookies
Current Session
Extension Cookies
Favicons
Google Profile.ico
Last Session
Login Data
Network Action Predictor
Network Persistent State
Origin Bound Certs
Preferences
QuotaManager
Secure Preferences
Shortcuts
Top Sites
TransportSecurity
Web Data
```

My extensions:

```
PageChopper
Adblock Plus
Tampermonkey
Auto-Translate
Stylish - Custom themes for any website
Selection Search
Extensions Manager (aka Switcher)
Flashcontrol
Clickable Links
SmoothScroll
MultiHighlighter
Session Buddy
```